# Function is not being called on every element of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm practicing some Python, this program takes multiple int input, stores it in a list and then it prints them out and makes a comment on each one.

```
rnumber = 500

perclist = [int(e) for e in input("Enter the percentages you want to comment: (separated by spaces) ").split()]

listlen = len(perclist)

def percentage(a, b):
    return 100 * (float(a) / float(b))

def comment(a, b):
    if percentage(a, b) <= 29:
        print("That is a low percentage")
    elif percentage(a, b) >= 30 and percentage(a, b) <= 69:
        print("That is a medium percentage")
    elif percentage(a, b) >= 70:
        print("That is a high percentage")

listlen = str(listlen)

print("Total inputs: " + listlen)

percprint = [(e*5) for e in perclist]

print(percprint)

for e in percprint:
    comment(e, rnumber)
```

Technically it doesn't show any error, but I know it's not working properly because whenever I input more than 14 numbers (or so) it always "forgets" to apply comment on some numbers, thus let's say I write 25 inputs, it only prints the comment of 17.
 I think I'm missing something here, can you help me out?

UPDATE: I found the bug; the issue was in `comment`. I changed the parameters of the conditionals and it's fixed.
 Apparently it didn't apply the function on some results because these percentages were out of range of the conditions, as some of you pointed out.
 Thanks to each one of you who gave help!

Comment: What is supposed to happen for values like `29.5`? You have gaps in your cases.

Comment: It's supposed to only accept integers

Comment: But -- `percentage` returns a float.

Comment: Unable to reproduce this i have used 29 inputs and got 29 lines of output

Comment: As an aside, there's really no need to cache `len()` calls in Python. It's an O(1) property lookup, unlike in C, and saving the result in a variable obfuscates what length you're accessing and is bug prone in terms of keeping the real length and your cached length synced up. I recommend using `len(your_list)` every time.

Comment: `float(a) / float(b)` is the same as `a/b` in Python 3. I am also unable to reproduce any bug. Please describe an exact input which leads to the bug.

Comment: Your loop ignores numbers between 29 and 30, or between 69 and 70. Your percentages are floats, so 29.5 is a possible value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code, and without an explicit failing test case scenario, what could be happening is mentioned by John Coleman in the comments, which is a hole in the ranges you test for in the `comment` function. Together with some code cleanup here's what I would write:

```
def percentage(a, b):
    return 100 * (float(a) / float(b))

def comment(a, b):
    if percentage(a, b) <= 29:
        print("That is a low percentage")

    elif percentage(a, b) <= 69:  # notice the range from above 29
        print("That is a medium percentage")

    elif percentage(a, b) > 69:        # notice the range from above 69
        print("That is a high percentage")

def main():
    rnumber = 500
    perclist = [int(e) for e in input("Enter the percentages you want to comment: (separated by spaces) ").split()]
    percprint = [(e*5) for e in perclist]

    print("Total inputs: " + len(perclist))
    print(percprint)
    for e in percprint:
        comment(e, rnumber)


main()
```

If you want to include a progress counter as per your comment, you could do something like:

```
def comment(a, b, i):
    if percentage(a, b) <= 29:
        print("[%s] That is a low percentage" % i)

    elif percentage(a, b) <= 69:  # notice the range from above 29
        print("[%s] That is a medium percentage" % i)

    elif percentage(a, b) > 69:        # notice the range from above 69
        print("[%s] That is a high percentage" % i)
```

And use `enumerate` in `main()` as:

```
    for i, e in enumerate(percprint):
        comment(e, rnumber, i+1)
```

If - instead - you want to include the value being commented, you could do something like:

```
def comment(a, b):
    if percentage(a, b) <= 29:
        print("[%s] That is a low percentage" % a)

    elif percentage(a, b) <= 69:  # notice the range from above 29
        print("[%s] That is a medium percentage" % a)

    elif percentage(a, b) > 69:        # notice the range from above 69
        print("[%s] That is a high percentage" % a)
```

and `main()` remains same as the first version in this answer.

Comment: I don't think that that is the issue since if it were the issue it would show up with an input like `29 30 31 69 70 71`, but it doesn't. OP's bug is likely to lie outside of the code that they posted. Also, wouldn't `elif 29 < percentage(a, b) <= 69:` be better rendered as simply `elif percentage(a,b) <= 69`, and the final clause a simple `else`?

Comment: @JohnColeman You're right, I adjusted the `if` statement. And yes, there seems to be something else going on.

Comment: Guys I'm wondering how could I add a counter at the beginning of comment() output. For example: [1] That is a medium percentage. [2] That is a high percentage.

Comment: You mean, a counter for the total progress?

Comment: Actually it would be better if it recalled the value being commented, from perclist variable. How different would that be from the code you updated recently?

Comment: Just added that sample.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely fine if you are only going to take integers as inputs but if you want to consider the floating numbers also then you can try out this code. It would run for all

```
def percentage(a, b):
    return 100 * (float(a) / float(b))


def comment(a, b):
    if percentage(a, b) <= 29:
        print("That is a low percentage")
    elif percentage(a, b) <= 69:
        print("That is a medium percentage")
    else:
        print("That is a high percentage")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rnumber = 500
    perclist = [float(e) for e in input("Enter the percentages you want to comment: (separated by spaces) ").split()]
    print(perclist)
    listlen = len(perclist)
    listlen = str(listlen)

    print("Total inputs: " + listlen)

    percprint = [(e*5) for e in perclist]

    print(percprint)

    for e in percprint:
        comment(e, rnumber)
```